# Spring Boot - API call to retrieve data for a given date

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to call an api to get all items for a given date. I would like to be able to call e.g. localhost:8080/item/2018-03-03 but this is returning nothing. At the moment calling localhost:8080/item gives me the correct data I need using the getAllItems() method but I want to be able to supply a date using the getItemByDate method.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I have used this successfully passing in ID's previously.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/item")
public class ItemController {

  @Autowired private ItemService itemService;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public List<Item> getAllItems() {
    return itemService.getItems(LocalDate.now());
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/{date}")
  public List<Item> getItemByDate(
      @PathVariable(value = "date") LocalDate itemDate) {
    return itemService.getItems(itemDate);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE** 
I managed to fix my issue by modifying my getItemByDate method:

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/{date}")
  public List<Item> getItemByDate(
      @PathVariable(value = "date") String strDate) {
    LocalDate itemDate = LocalDate.parse(strDate);
    return itemService.getItem(itemDate);
  }
```

Comment: show your repository class. And also the reason it is not working is because, in database date is stored with time

Comment: when I pass in LocalDate.now() it works correctly so I dont think my issue is in the getItems method.